# How to Avoid or Test Randomness in Functional Programming

Tags: javascript, testing, design-patterns, random, functional-programming

I started to make a dungeon-game that creates randomly new dungeons.

Currently I write the function `createRoom` that returns a new room object based on the arguments. This function is called in `createDungeon`, but it receivs random parameters there.

```
function createRoom (width = 1, height = 1, topLeftCoordinate = {x: 0, y: 0}) {
  return {
    width,
    height,
    topLeftCoordinate
  }
}

function createDungeon (numberOfRooms, rooms = []) {
  if (numberOfRooms <= 0) {
    return rooms
  }
  const randomWidth = getRandomNumber(5, 10)
  const randomHeight = getRandomNumber(5, 10)
  const randomTopLeftCoordinate = {x: getRandomNumber(5, 10), y: getRandomNumber(5, 10)}
  return createDungeon (
    numberOfRooms - 1, 
    rooms.concat(Room.create(randomWidth, randomHeight, randomTopLeftCoordinate))
  )
}
```

I don't know if this is the right why, because I don't how to test `createDungeon`. I can only test if this function retuns an array and the length of the array.. Is this enough or is there a design pattern for the randomness?

Comment: You can try to put some specific numbers instead of getRandomNumber

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, first off I'm assuming that your `getRandomNumber` is in fact a pseudorandom seed-based generator with a global seed. To make it more in the spirit of *true* FP, you'd need to make the seed/generator passing and mutation explicit, but that's not something you absolutely have to do.

Now, the answer depends on what you want to test. If you need to make sure that your random generation provides the same values for a given seed (which is important when e.g. you want to have "world seeds" like Minecraft does), then it's enough to hardcode the seed and then proceed with known output.

An important note is that when using a global random number generator, every number "drawn out" of it will impact the future numbers. This means that if you change your test code later on to include some other numbers *before* the previous test cases, your hardcoded values will completely mismatch. You could mitigate that by ensuring that all independent test runs start with a fresh generator.

If you want to test the behavior in a more "reasonable" way, that is, whether the function generally behaves ok, you'll need to use more seeds and run it multiple times. Now whether the seeds are themselves random or hardcoded doesn't matter; the important difference is that your validation rules now can't test for specific value equality, but instead need to check for boundaries or some other range criteria.

Answer (score 0):

In general, test execution should be deterministic and repeatable, so dealing with randomness in tests should be avoided (there's a great book, Lasse Koskela's "Effective Unit Testing", where you can find out how to deal with randomness in tests, among many other issues).

This means, for example, that if you write a test to check what is the result of `createDungeon(3)`, the results of that call should always be the same, so the assertions you make about that result are always valid.

May I suggest a small refactor, in your example: the random number generator should be passed as an argument to createDungeon:

```
function createDungeon (numberOfRooms, randomGenerator, rooms = []) {
    ...
    const randomWidth = randomGenerator.getRandomNumber(5, 10)
    ...
}
```

In your tests, you pass a test double (a mock object) for your `randomGenerator`, previously set up to return some known values. You can use some mock framework like JsMockito, and then you can just do something like:

```
generator = mock(RandomGenerator);
when(generator).getRandomNumber(5,10).thenReturn(8);
// run the test
generateDungeon(3, generator);
// verify results
assert(...)
```